# How to grant a Service Principal read access to the Active Directory Groups?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, github-actions, active-directory-group, azure-service-principal

Currently I am trying to read the ObjectId of an Active Directory Group from a GitHub Action where I am logged in with a Service Principal.

The Service Principal is a Contributor with the following additional permissions:

```
"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write",
"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read"
```

when running the following command with the Azure CLI:

```
az ad group show -g {NAME OF GROUP}
```

I receive the following output:

```
ValidationError: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Error: Error: az cli script failed.
```

I have tried granting permission to the service principal through the Microsoft Graph API through the following permissions:

```
Directory.Read.All (Granted)
Group.Read.All (Granted)
```

However these are not sufficient to grant read permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to fix the issue(the sceond one is recommended):

1. This command essentially calls the `Azure AD Graph` not `Microsoft Graph`, so the permission of Microsoft Graph will not take effect, what you need here is the *Application permission*(not *Delegated permission*) `Directory.Read.All` in `Azure AD Graph`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Another way is to give the [Azure AD admin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) to the service principal, e.g. [`Directory Readers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers), this role's permission is less than `Directory.Read.All` above, and AAD Graph is a Supported legacy API, so the second way is recommended. After giving the role, wait for a while to take effect, then it will work fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy, I went with your second recommendation and it worked great, I appreciate the answer